# how to make `dict(a_instance_of_a_subclass_of_dict)` become a regular dict in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, dictionary, subclass

I have a subclass of dict, but when I am writing it into database, I want to convert it back to a regular dict first. I wanted to use `dict(a_instance_of_a_subclass_of_dict)` which looks like casting but I need to decide only certain keys are exported to the regular dict.

I don't know what special method of a mapping is called when you write `dict(mapping)` so I did this experiment:

```
class Mydict(dict):
    def __getattribute__(self, what):
        print 'getting attribute:', what

m = Mydict(x = 2, y = 3, z = 4)

print '--------- mark ---------'
print dict(m)
```

It prints:

```
--------- mark ---------
getting attribute: keys
{'y': 3, 'x': 2, 'z': 4}
```

It looks like `dict(mapping)` will call `keys` method of mapping. (Actually something weird happens here. `__getattribute__` returns `None` here but `dict` simply didn't rely on the return value and still gets the correct contents. Let's forget about this for now.)

Then I rewrote another subclass of dict like this:

```
class Mydict2(dict):
    def keys(self):
        print 'here keys'
        return ['x', 'y']

m2 = Mydict2(x = 2, y = 3, z = 4)

print '--------- mark2 ---------'
print dict(m2)
```

Output is this:

```
--------- mark2 ---------
{'y': 3, 'x': 2, 'z': 4}
```

It didn't call keys method. Weird again!

Can somebody explain this behavior? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cpython checks the presence of `keys` to decide if the argument is a dictionary-alike object:

```
    if (PyObject_HasAttrString(arg, "keys"))
        result = PyDict_Merge(self, arg, 1);
```

http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/dictobject.c#l1435

However, on a later stage, if it turns out that the argument is exactly a dict (or its subclass), it doesn't call `keys`, but rather accesses the internal hash table directly. `keys` is only called for dict-alikes, for example, this works as expected:

```
class Mydict2(UserDict):
    def keys(self):
        print 'here keys'
        return ['x', 'y']
```

My advice is to avoid fiddling with the system stuff and to add an explicit method like:

```
class Mydict2(dict):
    def export(self):
        return {k:self[k] for k in ['x', 'y']}
```

and call it when you're about to serialize your object for writing into the db.

Comment: Instead of an explicit method, it might be feasible to just use a `dict(<comprehension>)` expression depending on the complexity of selecting keys to by included.

Comment: Thanks. Your reference to the C source code is really good. That explains all the weird things I was talking about. I wanted to do the `dict(mapping)` because it looks like casting in c or Java. But my intention isn't easy to implement.